# Score to Grade converter, or: Why is my switch statement buggy? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm working on switch statements at the moment, and have a little function below that turn a given numerical score into a grade. Or at least that's what it's supposed to do, but somehow it all goes wrong, and I'm not sure why!

```
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {
 var grade = "";
  switch(score) {
 case 100>=score && score>=90: grade = "A";
   break;
 case 89>=score && score>=80: grade = "B";
   break;
 case 79>=score && score>=70: grade = "C";
   break;
 case 69>=score && score>=60: grade = "D";
   break;
 case 59>=score && score>=0: grade = "F";
   break;
 case score>100 || score<0: grade = "INVALID SCORE";
 } return grade;
}

convertScoreToGrade(10);
```

For example, when I input the number 10 I only get an empty string, which suggests that the relevant case isn't evaluated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your cases all result in boolean values, and `score` isn't a boolean, so you'll never get a match. You could do `switch(true) {...`, but `if/else` statements are probably better

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) says *the switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on your example, here is a modification to make your code work**

The big take away here is you match the parameter you pass into the switch statement. So passing a boolean value of true means that if your condition is true, that will be the case.

IMO, a switch statement is what you should use for this case. It's a small amount of cases (5), and is very readable for anyone who will work on or maintain this code at a later point.

```js
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {

  // Check for invalid scores first
  if(typeof score !== 'number' || score < 0 || score > 100)
    return "INVALID SCORE";

  var grade = "";
 
  // Pass a boolean value, remember we are matching this value
  // EX: (score < 90) is true when score is 0 - 89
  switch(true) {
    case score < 60: 
      grade = "F";
      break;
    case score < 70: 
      grade = "D";
      break;
    case score < 80: 
      grade = "C";
      break;
    case score < 90: 
      grade = "B";
      break;
    case score <= 100:
      grade = "A";
      break;
  }
  
  // If you want partial grades
  if(score % 10 <= 3 && score !== 100 )
    grade += "-";
  else if(score % 10 >= 7 || score == 100)
    grade += "+";
  
  return grade;
}

// These are small test cases to show you 
// that convertScoreToGrade works as defined
console.log(convertScoreToGrade(-1));
console.log(convertScoreToGrade(101));
console.log(convertScoreToGrade('The dog ate it.'));

var i = 50;
while(i <= 100){
  console.log(i, 'should be', convertScoreToGrade(i));
  i += 4;
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks so much! I picked the wrong parameter for the switch statement in the code above, as you say.

Comment: Any comments for the down vote? I would like to get feedback as to what was wrong. @user211309, if you like the answer - can you please mark it as correct?

Comment: Sure thing--I think I just did! I'd upvote your answer but can't (yet...).

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {
    // scores is an array of objects
    // Each element in the scores array has two properties, grade and score
    // grade is the letter grade, score is the minimum score to achieve that grade
    var i,l,scores = [{ grade: 'A', score: 90},
        {grade: 'B',score : 80},
        {grade: 'C',score: 70},
        {grade: 'D',score: 60 }];

    // Ensure score is between 0 and 100 inclusive
    if (score < 0 || score > 100) {
        return 'Invalid';
    }
    // Loop through all the scores and exit when the score is larger than the minimum
    l = scores.length;
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        if (score >= scores[i].score) {
            return scores[i].grade;
        }
    }

    // If the score was not found, the grade is an F
    return 'F';
}

console.log(convertScoreToGrade(82));
console.log(convertScoreToGrade(90));
console.log(convertScoreToGrade(50));
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the order of enumeration when using a `for-in`. It's completely valid for an implementation to change the order as it sees fit, which means that `'A'` is not necessarily first.

Comment: ...and you're not handling invalid scores.

Comment: @squint - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bad solution that you might think of that is clearly worse than the alternative but I already typed it and I think it's helpful for you to understand that this is how you'd handle it with if statements. Please have mercy on me for posting such lousy code.

```
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {
 var grade = "";
 if(score>=0){
   grade = "F";
 }
 if(score>=60){
    grade = "D";
 }
 if(score>=70){
    grade = "C";
 }
 if(score>=80){
   grade = "B";
 }
 if(score>=90){
   grade = "A";
 }
 if (score>100 || score<0){
   grade = "INVALID SCORE";
 }
 return grade;
}

convertScoreToGrade(10);
```